# Why is the value not assigned to state? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Why doesn't it assign a value to state? I don't quite understand why the first time it doesn't assign me a value, while the second time it is as it should be. I need to do a setState in the dbRef function because the outside does not see the values. What can I do so I can assign a value more times?

Below is the code with which I tried to assign values

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { dbRefMinMax, dbRefHist} from "./firebase";
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-3';

function Teststate () {
    const[state, setState] = useState ({
        
        d6:null,
        Max6:null,
        Min6:null,
        d7:null,
        Max7:null,
        Min7:null,
        labelMin:null,
        labelMax:null,
        Click:null
    })

    function handleClick(){
        setState({
            Click : 'Temperature'
        });
      }

    function handleClick2(){
        setState({
            Click : 'Pressure'
        })
      }
    useEffect(()=>{
        dbRefHist.limitToLast(6).on("value", snapshot => {
            var history = snapshot.val();
            var date6=Object.values(history)[5].date
            var tempMax6=Object.values(history)[5].tempmax
            var tempMin6=Object.values(history)[5].tempmin
            var pressMax6=Object.values(history)[5].pressuremax
            var pressMin6=Object.values(history)[5].pressuremin
            var dd = date6.split("-")[2].split(" ")[0];
            var mm = date6.split("-")[1].padStart(2, "0");
            var day6=dd+'.'+mm
            setState({
                d6:day6,
                Min6:tempMin6,
                Max6:tempMax6

            })
            console.log(state.d6)

           
            if (state.Click==='Pressure' ||state.Click===null){
                setState({
                   
                    Max6:pressMax6,
                    Min6:pressMin6,
                    labelMin:"Ciśnienie minimalne",
                    labelMax:"Ciśnienie maksymalne"
            })
   
            }else if (state.Click==='Temperature'){
                setState({
          
                    Max6:tempMax6,
                    Min6:tempMin6,
                    labelMin:"Temperatura minimalna",
                    labelMax:"Temperatura maksymalna"
            })
            }
        })

            dbRefMinMax.on("value", snapshot => {
                var minmax = snapshot.val();
                var date7=minmax.date
                var tempMax7=minmax.tempmax
                var tempMin7=minmax.tempmin
                var pressMax7=minmax.pressuremax
                var pressMin7=minmax.pressuremin
                var [year,month, day,] = date7.split('-');
                var dd = date7.split("-")[2].split(" ")[0];
                var mm = date7.split("-")[1].padStart(2, "0");
                date7=dd+'.'+mm
                setState({
                   d7:date7,
                   Min7:tempMin7,
                   Max7:tempMax7
               })
               console.log(state.d7)

            if (state.Click==='Pressure' ||state.Click===null){
                setState({
                    Max7:pressMax7,
                    Min7:pressMin7,
            })
   
            }else if (state.Click==='Temperature'){
                setState({
                    Max7:tempMax7,
                    Min7:tempMin7,
            })
            }
        })
},[]);

return (
      <div>
        <Line redraw={true}
          data={{labels: [state.d1, state.d2, state.d3, state.d4, state.d5, state.d6, state.d7],
            datasets: [
                {
                label: [state.labelMin],
                data: [11, 12, 12,13, 23, 23,23],
                fill: false,
                // backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.2)",
                borderColor: "#129FE5"
                },
                {
                label: state.labelMax,
                data: [22, 33, 44, 11, 22, 22, 11],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "rgba(227,22,22,1)"
                }
            ]}}
        />
            <div>
        <button type="button" className="button" onClick={handleClick}>Temperatura</button>
        <button className="button" type="button" onClick={handleClick2}><span className="text">Ciśnienie</span></button>
        
      </div>
      <p>{state.Click}</p>
      <p>{state.Max7}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Below is the code that shows what's really going on, it only displays state.d7 - as if it can only do one setState and chooses the last one

```
function Teststate2 () {
    const[state, setState] = useState ({
        
    })

   
    useEffect(()=>{
        var  date6='12.11'
        setState({
            d6 : date6
        })
        
         var date7='13.11'
         setState({
            d7 : date7
        })
            


},[]);

return (
      
       <div>
      <p>{state.Click}</p>
      <p>{state.d7}</p>
      <p>{state.d6}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State [updates are batched](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates) and take place after the function execution

```
function Teststate2 () {
    const[state, setState] = useState ({
        
    })

   
useEffect(() => {

        // updates will be batched/queued
        var  date6='12.11'       
        setState({
            d6 : date6
        })
        // will replace all previous state
        // { d6: '12.11' }
        
        var date7='13.11'
        // replaces the previous state
        setState({
            d7 : date7
        })
        // { d7: '13.11' }

        // possible options
        // either update state at once
        setState({
            d6 : date6,
            d7 : date7
        });
        // { d6: '12.11', d7: '13.11' }

        // use state updater
        setState(existinState => ({
            ...existinState
            d6 : date6,
            d7 : date7
        });
        // { ///other state props 
        // d6: '12.11', 
        // d7: '13.11' 
        // }

       // even this should work as per the new docs
       setState(s => ({
            ...s,
            d6 : date6
       })

        setState(s => ({
            ...s,
            d7 : date7
       })
        // { ///other state props 
        // d6: '12.11', 
        // d7: '13.11' 
        // }
           

},[]);

return (
      
       <div>
      <p>{state.Click}</p>
      <p>{state.d7}</p>
      <p>{state.d6}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Hope it helps you sort out the actual problem

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same d7 is visible and d6 is not

Comment: I will deleted this answer as its dint help, I suggest you make minimal reproducible example so we can understand the exact problem and find a proper solution

Comment: I edited the question, could you take a look?

Comment: @kara6667 I still have not understood the exact requirment, but I have edite the answer with possible answers which could guide you in solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you expect `console.log(state.d6)` to log `Object.values(history)[5].date`. However, the first time, it (probably) logs `null`.

This is because state is only updated for the next render.

That means that

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

console.log(counter); // will yield 0 at first render, 1 at second, 2 at third, etc

setCounter(counter + 1);

console.log(counter); // will always yield the same as first console.log(counter)
```

Comment: d6 should be visible because there is a value (if i console.log(Object.values(history)[5].date) I get value

Comment: The point is, even though `Object.values(history)[5].date` is defined, and therefore `console.log(Object.values(history)[5].date)` prints its value, **right after** you do `setState(Object.values(history)[5].date)`, `state` does not equal `Object.values(history)[5].date`. It is only on the next render that state will be updated, so if you `console.log(Object.values(history)[5].date, state)`, the first will have a value but not the second